# Facebook newsfeed in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I want to create a Facebook like newsfeed for my users that basically does the following

- it keeps track of the activities of users and their friends
- users can see recent friend activities on their newsfeed

but i am not quite sure how best to implement this in mysql. Like what sort of tables will I need? What is the structure of these tables? What will I store in these tables? How will I keep track of user and friends activities. I want to build an efficient system that will scale up. I prefer working with PHP and Mysql if possible!

I was thinking of having a NEWSFEED table and when a user does something (posts a comment, etc), I add an entry to that table for the user's friends and the user himself that will show up on their newsfeed.

The table structure would be as follows

```
uid INT
activity ENUM
activity_id INT
```

So let's say I have a comments table with the following structure:

```
title VARCHAR(255)
message TEXT
```

If the user posts to that table and an entry with ID=5 gets created for that user, then the following entry will be added to the NEWSFEED table

uid=3 activity="comment" activity_id=5

that means that to display the newsfeed for each user, I would have to do the following:

SELECT * FROM newsfeed WHERE UID = ....

```
FOR EVERY ROW:
CHECK activity type (if activity == 'comment')
 **QUERY the corresponding table and display the result (so I would query the comments table an display the person's comment)**
```

I am thinking of deleting entries more than >3 months old to prevent the table from getting too huge. But I don't like that I am doing independent queries to display for each activity type (just as I did above where I queried the COMMENTS table to display the comment whose ID is mentioned in the NEWSFEED table).

Comment: are you asking us to program this for you?   This is way too broad a question.

It sounds like you need to do some database tutorials and come back when and if you get stuck with something specific.

Comment: no I would like some help with the design, if that is possible. not the coding.

Comment: a table of people, a table of feeds, a lookup table of friends i.e. people matched to other people could do it.

A page would then search for all your friends and their associated feeds.

Wanting details like "what would I store in these tables" comes under learning database design.  You will make mistakes but that's how you learn.

TO be honest, if you are new to this sort of thing, you likely need someone who is expert in scalability otherwise down the rack you are going to slap your forehead numerous times...trust me, I have the bruises.

Comment: FWIW - notice the complete lack of interest in answers from people?  I suspect it is because, like me, your question is seen as asking others to help you with the basics.  To get a response from the SO community there is an expectation that you have done as much as you can and you need some help with something particularly perplexing - even if it is basic.